# Is there a more intuitive way to define tensor products other than using free vector spaces?

Tags: tensor-products

Tensor products come up a lot in some literature I am reading. but every time I go to Wikipedia, it says a prerequisite for understanding tensor products is understanding free vector spaces. Having read the Wikipedia page,  I still don't understand what a free vector space is. I get regular ones but not this "free" kind. so I then cannot understand tensor products.

So is there a way to explain tensor products in a more intuitive way than using free vector spaces?

Comment: Dis you ever see the construction of polynomial ring R[X] over a commutative ring R as the `free R-algebra built on $\mathbf N$`? It's more or less the same notion. What is meant by the `free vector space built on a set S` is that one obtains canonically the base of the vector space. If K is the base field, it's simply the vector space $K^{(S)}$.

Comment: A "free vector space on a set" is needed only to understand the construction in the proof of tensor products. They are essentially never used in applications of tensor products. And, by the way, a "free vector space" is a regular vector space that is just built in a special way. Any "free vector space" is a vector space, and because all (nonzero) vector spaces have bases every vector space is in turn a free vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the tensor product of 2 vector spaces E and F over a field K (or 2 modules over a commutative field) is a vector space G which is a solution to the following so-called `universal problem:

1) There exists a bilinear map $\varphi\colon E\times F\longrightarrow G$.
2) For any vector space L and any bilinear map $f\colon E\times F\longrightarrow L$, there exists a *unique* `linear`map $u\colon G \longrightarrow L$ such that $f=u\circ \varphi$ (this is best described as a commutative diagram).

Technically a solution to this problem is obtained with the vector space $ K^{(S)}= $ families of elements of K indexed by S with finite support. In case S is finite, you can think of, say $K^3$, whose elements are all triples $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ of elements of K.

Answer (score 0):

**Other opinion:** To start to grasp the concept of tensor or tensors in general on a secure footing you have to understand *vector duality* and how the *tensor product* of rank-one-tensors to build the rank-two-tensors which are also dubbed bilinear forms or bilinear maps.

Comment: Not all bilinear maps are 2-forms. 2-forms are alternating bilinear maps.

Comment: ok @MattSamuel, I should write bilinear forms instead, right?

Comment: Bilinear form is correct.